# How to validate input number length with angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to validate a 9 digits number using angular,

this is in my modal :

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="id" required>
```

i tried pattern = [0-9]{9}, seems its passing every number that its getting . 
I want to pass only number 000000000 - 9999999999 , min-max also not working for me.

this is what my app adding to this class:

```
 class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid-number ng-invalid ng-invalid-required"
```

thank u !

Comment: you have min max attributes

Comment: Cant use it, minimum value can be also 000000101 for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried both `ngMinlength` and `ngMaxlength` at the same time?

Example:

```
<input type="text" ng-minlength=9 ng-maxlength=9 />
```

Check out the official documentation regarding this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Very nice tutorial about form validation: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html

Answer (score 10):

I just use a `pattern` as validator. The following code will make the field `required` and must be `only digits` of length `10`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.firstForm = this.fb.group({
        firstCtrl: ['', [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{10}$'), Validators.required]],
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Rahul Desai you have to use ngMinlength and ngMaxlength.
But since you want to use numbers you have to change the code a little bit to this

```
<input type="number" ng-model="id" ng-minlength=9 ng-maxlength=9 required />
```

To be honest I don't know what to do with `class="form-control"`. Maybe you can add it or leave it out?!

Anyway you can also try this

```
<input type="number" ng-model="id" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,9}$/" required />
```

You shouldn't need min/max attribute anymore.

**EDIT:**
I guess I made a mistake with the second one. It should be either

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{9}$/"
```

or

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{9,9}$/"
```

Comment: it didnt work for me. it accepts (3...5) or (2.5.44)

Comment: @Alaa' what do you mean exactly? Did you try both or just one of the provided solutions? I guess I made a mistake in the second one. I didn't test it back then. The pattern one should work for sure. I don't know if angular allows dots in type 'number'.

Answer (score 2):

With Reactive Forms you should compose validators in such a way:

```
formControlYourField: [
  "",
  Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(9),
    Validators.maxLength(9),
    Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"),
  ]),
]
```

And of course in your **.html**

```
<input
  matInput
  required
  formControlName="formControlYourField"
  type="text"
  placeholder="123456789"
/>
```